# How can I find parent records without children?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following SQL Query

```
SELECT T0.*
FROM Accounting T0 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(ParentAccountId) FROM Accounting WHERE ParentAccountId = T0.AccountId) = 0
```

It gives me the accounts that have no child. I'm trying to use a Lambda Expression to get the same result on my code.

```
List<Accounting> Items = await _context.Accounting.Where(q => q.ParentAccountId == q.AccountId).ToListAsync();
```

How can I place the COUNT condition on my code?

Comment: ASP.NET is a web framework, it doesn't query databases. What you posted looks like LINQ over Entity Framework  code. Is it EF or EF Core, and what version?

Comment: In any case, you aren't trying to count anything, you're trying to find if the current record has no children. In EF (and all ORMs) instead of joining tables you specify relations and let the ORM generate the queries. If your `Accounting` entity had a `Children` collection, you could write `_context.Accounting.Where(q=>!q.Children.Any())`

Comment: You could also use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in SQL, and then it becomes more obvious to use a corresponding `!yourCollection.Any(q => ...)` in LINQ.

Comment: And a lot faster too - the server doesn't have to calculate the count to decide whether there are any related records, simply finding one matching record is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
List<Accounting> Items = await _context.Accounting.Where(q => q.Accounting.Where(r => r.ParentAccountId == q.AccountId).count()==0).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `q` is an Accounting item, but you are using it as if it equals `_context`.

Comment: q is a parent element it's not a _context, so it have Accounting element.

Comment: worked with a minor correction using                 Items = await _context.Accounting.Where(q => _context.Accounting.Where(r => r.ParentAccountId == q.AccountId).Count() == 0).ToListAsync();

Comment: Sounds good, so in this case you don't have relationship between ParentAccountId and AccountId

Answer (score 2):

***Shortest Answer:***

```
List<MyParent> noKidParents = myDbContext.MyParents.Where(par => !par.MyChildren.Any());
```

***Short Answer:***

```
////using System;
////    using System.Collections.Generic;
////    using System.Linq;
////    using System.Threading;
////    using System.Threading.Tasks;

////    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyParentEntity>> GetNoChildrenRows(CancellationToken token)
    {
        List<MyParentEntity> returnItems = await this.entityDbContext.MyParents.Where(ent => !ent.MyChildren.Any()).ToListAsync(token);

        return returnItems;
    }
```

***Longer Explained Answer:***

You should not prefer "Count" answers.

You should prefer ".Any()" (or !.Any() in this case) answers.

Given POCO's

```
public partial class MyChildEntity
{
    public Guid MyChildKey { get; set; } /* PK */

    public Guid MyParentUUID { get; set; } /* FK to the "parent" */

    public MyParentEntity ParentMyParent { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class MyParentEntity
{

    public MyParentEntity()
    {
        this.MyChilds = new List<MyChildEntity>();
    }

    public Guid MyParentKey { get; set; } /* PK */

    public ICollection<MyChildEntity> MyChilds { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapping like this (mine is coded to EF Core, but the final answer (the .Where EF query below) should work the same, even if you're not using EF Core, but a DotNet Framework EF.. as long as everything is "mapped" correctly)

```
////    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
////    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

   public class MyChildMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyChildEntity>
    {
        public const string SchemaName = "dbo";
        public const string TableName = "MyChild";

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyChildEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable(TableName, SchemaName );

            builder.HasKey(k => k.MyChildKey);
            builder.Property(cnpk => cnpk.MyChildKey).HasColumnName("MyChildUUID");
            builder.Property(req => req.MyChildKey).IsRequired();

            builder.Property(cn => cn.MyParentUUID).HasColumnName("MyParentUUID");
            builder.Property(req => req.MyParentUUID).IsRequired();



            builder.HasIndex(ind => new { ind.MyParentUUID, ind.MyChildName }).IsUnique(true);

            builder.HasOne<MyParentEntity>(e => e.ParentMyParent)
            .WithMany(d => d.MyChilds)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.MyParentUUID).HasConstraintName("MyParentUUIDFK");
        }
    }
```

and

```
public class MyParentMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyParentEntity>
{
    public const string SchemaName = "dbo";
    public const string TableName = "MyParent";

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyParentEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableName, SchemaName);

        builder.HasKey(k => k.MyParentKey);
        builder.Property(cnpk => cnpk.MyParentKey).HasColumnName("MyParentUUID");

        builder.Property(req => req.MyParentKey).IsRequired();


    }
}
```

and a context like this:

```
////using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
public class MyEntitiesDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyEntitiesDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyEntitiesDbContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }


    public DbSet<MyParentEntity> MyParents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MyChildEntity> MyChilds { get; set; }
}
```

Your EF code can look like this:

```
////using System;
////    using System.Collections.Generic;
////    using System.Linq;
////    using System.Threading;
////    using System.Threading.Tasks;

////    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyParentEntity>> GetNoChildrenRows(CancellationToken token)
    {
        List<MyParentEntity> returnItems = await this.entityDbContext.MyParents.Where(ent => !ent.MyChildren.Any()).ToListAsync(token);

        return returnItems;
    }
```

NOTE, in Sql Server, the EF "where" query above.... does (properly) equate to a "NOT EXISTS" query:

```
SELECT [m].[MyParentUUID]
FROM [dbo].[MyParent] AS [m]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[MyChild] AS [m0]
    WHERE [m].[MyParentUUID] = [m0].[MyParentUUID]))
```